# Can @group annotation be used on class level in phpunit

Tags: php, annotations, phpunit

I am trying to explore the possibility of using `@group` or `@author` annotation on class level, so that I may assign some sort of ownership to specific people. Also, with this, I plan to macro-manage things, like: if I want one or more classes to run (in their entirety), I can just specify their groups as, say ABC and then use `--groups` option.

Presently, I think `@groups` or `@author` is used on test case level only, and not on Test Class level. What I think is that one class may have hundreds of test cases, and writing `@author` or `@group` would be very tedious. And in future, if the ownership changes, we need to change the annotation attribute everywhere. Hence, is there any way to specify `@group` or something like that on class level?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes you can use `@group` on test classes. However I could not find it in the documentation so it can be something that will change. (I've checked it on PHPUnit v3.7.37)

*Note:* this is something that is fairly easy to try, I'd even say quicker than asking it here. Also typing "phpunit class level group annotation" into google yields a [blog page](http://mikenaberezny.com/2007/09/04/better-phpunit-group-annotations/) about this as the first result.